# Align in CSS doesn't work with a button to another HTML page

Tags: html, css

This is the button I'm talking about:

```
    <div class="registerButton">
        <a href="register/register.html"><button id="registerButton">Register here!</button></a>
    </div>
```

I've added the class later on because I had thought the problem was that the id only had the button but not the link. I have tried every possible align option. `alignment`, `align-content` , `align-self` , etc. But that isn't the problem. My button still wasn't aligned to the right. This is my CSS:

```
#registerButton {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px cadetblue;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-style: none;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-out, border-radius 0.2s ease-out, box-shadow 0.2s ease-out;
}

#registerButton:hover {
    background-color: darkorange;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px cadetblue;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.registerButton {
    alignment: right;
    align-content: right;
    align-items: right;
    align-self: right;
    text-align-all: right;
    horiz-align: right;
    -moz-box-align: end;
}
```

It looks a bit messy but looking at this you could understand me. Every alignment didn't work for me. I've tried them all with the id and class. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

While writing this I tried the align attribute in the div tags. That worked, but why doesn't it work in the CSS file?

Comment: try just `text-align: right` on `.registerButton`. Do note that it is invalid HTML to have a `button` element inside an anchor element...

Comment: Thank you for the comment. JetBrains doesn't consider it als invalid nor warns me of any erros about the button element inside the anchor element. The page loads just fine with the button linking to the register.html file. I've tried the property and it finally works. It looks like I tried the wrong alignment first. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this. Here's a simple solution using flexbox:

```
.registerButton {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

FYI

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I hope this will work. But my question stays. Why do all those alignment properties don't work?

Comment: They don't work because they either a) don't exist or b) are not applicable in your situation.

Comment: It works fine now! The answer above helped me. It looks like I had to try `text-align: right` first. And only that. It doesn't work with more alignment properties.

Answer (score 0):

you mainly miss "text-align:right".add this .registerButton class.that's will work.

one more thing, that's not valid according to [validator.w3](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) that button use in anchor tag.

hope clear

Thank you.